# Running Java program on Tomcat as a service

Tags: java, tomcat, service

I developed a java program which runs on Apache Tomcat server.

At the moment i am running the program on eclipse.

My question is how can i run the program on the server as a Service, and without needing to enter Eclipse for it?

I am new ti this, so i am looking for directions.

And one more thing, i also have a program which include JSP pages, what is the process in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this http://www.easywayserver.com/blog/java-run-program-automatically-on-tomcat-startup/ help?

Comment: I think you better look for a tutorial. Perhaps try google ;-) .. Have a look here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/ApacheTomcat/article.html and here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseWTP/article.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean when you say enter eclipse for it. You can install tomcat on server where you want to run the program and deploy your application there. Once deployed you can start the tomcat and that should work. Tomcat should also serve as the JSP engine for your deployed application.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I have the Tomcat installed on my Server as a Service. how do i perform the deployment of my application on the Tomcat?

Comment: you can use the tomcat manager to deploy app or put your war file in the webapps directory. http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/manager-howto.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to Export the project as a WAR file. Right click on the project -> Export -> WAR File. You can then drop the war file in the `webapps` directory of Tomcat.

Comment: I do this. but the project doesn't appear in Windows Services... How can I fix it ?!

Comment: You need to install Tomcat as a service then drop the war in the web apps folder